# Get custom fields from the directoy

Tags: google-app-maker

How to access (read) custom fields from the directoy?
If I create the Directory Model the custom field of the directory are not shown.
Has someone done this before with App Maker?

Best regards

Karl

Answer (score 2):

Directory Model is read only. You can try to create Calculated Datasource and call AdminDirectory advanced service to get user records with custom fields:

1. Enable 'Google Admin Directory API'

   - Click Settings gear button on the top right
   - Select App Settings tab
   - Scroll to Advanced Services section
   - Add 'Google Admin Directory API' service
2. Create Calculated Model with directory fields you need (let's name it CustomDirectory)
3. In the calculated model's datasource server script you can add code like this to query user record from the Directory:

```js
var email = query.filters.Email._equals;
var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email);
var record = app.models.CustomDirectory.newRecord();

record.Email = email;
record.FieldA = user.FieldA;
record.FieldB = user.FieldB;
...
return [record];
```

4. Query calculated datasource from the client:

```js
var ds = app.datasources.CustomDirectory;

ds.query.filters.Email._equals = 'bob@example.com';
ds.load(function() {
  console.log(ds.item);
});
```

You can even avoid writing client side code, if you use bindings magic.

**Notes:**

- Since I'm not Directory admin, I had no chance to test if all links of this chain work.
- Most likely you'll need to deploy your app as developer to let all your app access Google Admin Directory API.

**Further reading:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/identity
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated